# How to get specific values from returned HttpResponse

Tags: java, android, json, api, http

i am getting a httpresponse with an api but how to get specific fields from that response? Example returned response is like this:

```
{"test": {
   "id": 179512,
   "name": "Test",
   "IconId": 606,
   "revisionDate": 139844341200,
   "Level": 20
}}
```

For example, i just want id field.

```
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String getURL = url;
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
            HttpResponse responseGet = null;
            try {
                responseGet = client.execute(get);
                HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
                Log.e("deneme", response);
                return response;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is up to the API how it returns it's data, what you should be asking is how am I going to parse this data and for me this is one of the pains of static types languages.

I personally use Jackson in all my projects to parse json, mostly because it plays nicely with spring.

Here is a very simple example of what you are trying to accomplish using Jackson

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-tree-model-example/

Comment: Do i have to download source to use this?

Comment: No, you want the libraries, they are available in the Maven repositories

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with what parsing means?

Parsing is basically taking data like that (usually a long String) and converting it to data that you can actually use, or use easier at least.

You could do it yourself... but this is a very annoying thing to do unless you're learning.

You're using a JSON content type. There are a bunch of Java JSON parser libraries you can use. My favorite is GSON, but it requires a little bit of coding. You're probably better off just using a regular json library. Go to http://json.org/ and scroll to the bottom to find a million libraries you can use.

Comment: How can i implement Gson to my current code? Do i need to convert the HttpEntity to Gson? Convert string to Gson? Or Gson have something to get data from my url?